# Storing dynamic numbers in database Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I am trying to figure out the best way to store a price into the database. The problem is that I have 2 different types of numbers:

1. Fixed price
2. From/To price

I want to allow the user to choose the budget they want, take their input and properly put it into my database. For example, you want to upload a book information and you can say that the price of this book is $100 or from $50 to $100. In other words, it can ether be $100 or it can be from $50 to $100.

I did a research and I found that I can simple add two extra columns to my database but I am wondering if later on it can effect on my website speed since one or two of my columns will be empty which is not good.

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: I remember that postgres could accept filed that stores a hash, It's psql v9 or higher as i guess, It would be good if you  store "low_interval" and "high_interval" into a hash and store that hash in just one field, Hope this helps.

Comment: @AmrAdel thank you for the answer. I am using `SQL` for the `development` and `Postgres` for `production`. Anyways, I will think about it. Thank you one more time.

Comment: you are welcome :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you model that contain the price attributes add:

```
 serialize :price, Array
```

Then simply check array length. If array length is one then its a fixed price value. It the array length is 2 for example like this [100, 200] then first part is your "From" value which is 100 and second part is your "To" value.

Comment: Interesting, thank you! I will try to solve my problem with your solution :)

Comment: Glad to help @AnthonyBrooks :D Merry Christmas !! Have fun coding

Comment: will it effect on the website speed since I have an extra validation in my database?

Comment: Merry Christmas to you too!

Comment: I would say that the first serious downside to serialization is write amplification. If you are constantly making small updates to one piece of data in a very large blob, the effort MySQL has to go to is greatly increased. For your case I think it will not have a great impact on performance.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and time :)